# Angular 17 WebSocket is not defined

Tags: angular, networking, websocket

I have a SpringBoot application, where I configured a WebSocket, which I can connect to with Postman. I have it up on ws://localhost:8050. With only one namespace,"socket".

I tried configuring a native angular websocket and a simple connect, running into an internal server error.

[[image: postman_answer]]

I tried to create the WebSocket connection like this.

```
    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8050/socket")
```

I am not importing any library like 'ws' for this constructor, it is simply the native one.

I get this error.

```
[vite] Internal server error: WebSocket is not defined
```

I expect to be able to connect to the server.

Comment: are you using SSR in your angular application?

Comment: I did not configure it specifically. But I can see that there are a couple dependencies added after creating the project. 

E.g. I have this in my server.ts. import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
But in my angular.json I have this:
"development": {
              ...
              "ssr": false
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with SSR. You need to prevent server-side rendering or build tools from executing WebSocket code.

I would suggest to check if the window object is available before initializing the WebSocket.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8050/socket");
}
```

This will ensure the WebSocket is only created in a browser environment.

Or you could work with platformId and isPlatformBrowser. This is a better example for Angular as opposed to the first one, which is more JS.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  // Your html, scss etc...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private isBrowser: boolean;

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            // Connect to WebSockets here
        } else {
            // Work without websockets or do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach your Angular application should correctly differentiate between server and browser environments, and only attempt to use WebSockets when in the browser.